# Mostrar valores en lugar de id, devuelve vacio (LARAVEL)

Tags: laravel

SOLUCIONADO GRACIAS AL USUARIO element

Se debe crear en el migration el foreing key de esta forma:

```
$table->foreign('id_empresa')->references('id')->on('empresa');
```

El codigo estaba bien, solo faltaba esta relacion...GRACIAS.

Actualmente tengo una tabla llamada:
Departamento
otra
Empresa
La tabla departamento contiene id_empresa, la cual relaciona el departamento a la empresa, necesito mostrar el nombre de la empresa basado en el id que tengo en la tabla departamento, el modelo lo tengo asi:

```
class Departamento extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     */
    protected $table = 'departamentos';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['id_empresa','nombre_departamento'];

    public function empresa()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Empresa','id');
    }
}
```

Lo que hago aqui es relacionar empresa a departamento, luego en el controlador :

```
public function index()
    {
        // Departamentos query
        $departamentos = Departamento::with('empresa')->get();
        return view('departamento', compact('departamentos',$departamentos));
    }
```

En la vista:

```
@foreach ($departamentos as $departamento)  
                  <tr>
                                <td> {{$departamento->nombre_departamento}} </td>
                    <td> {{$departamento->empresa->nombre_empresa}} </td>
                            <td><a href="{{route('departamento.edit', $departamento->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                    <td><a href="{{route('departamento.delete', $departamento->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">{{ __('Eliminar') }}</a></td>
                  </tr>
                 @endforeach
```

Pero esto me resulta en un error:

```
 ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property of non-object (View: resources\views\departamento.blade.php)
```

Alguna idea de cual es el problema?

El error es en esta linea:

```
 <td> {{$departamento->empresa->nombre_empresa}} </td>
```

Agrego lo que me retorna el dd

```
Collection {#281 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Departamento {#285 ▶}
    1 => Departamento {#286 ▼
      #table: "departamentos"
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "id_empresa"
        1 => "nombre_departamento"
        2 => "nombre_empresa"
      ]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "id_empresa" => 1
        "nombre_departamento" => "Departamento Sistemas"
        "created_at" => "2019-01-21 17:07:29"
        "updated_at" => "2019-01-21 17:07:29"
      ]
      #original: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "id_empresa" => 1
        "nombre_departamento" => "Departamento Sistemas"
        "created_at" => "2019-01-21 17:07:29"
        "updated_at" => "2019-01-21 17:07:29"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "empresa" => null
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

Migrations de la tabla Departamento

```
class CreateDepartamentosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('departamentos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('id_empresa')->unsigned();
            $table->string('nombre_departamento');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('departamentos');
    }
}
```

Tabla Empresa

class CreateEmpresaTable extends Migration
{

```
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('empresa', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre_empresa');
            $table->string('direccion');
            $table->string('ciudad');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('empresa');
    }
}
```

Comment: mmm no, me da error Undefined index: nombre_empresa  , empresa me devuelve null segun dd , la base de datos tiene informacion con ese id en la tabla empresa.

Comment: entiendo agrega a tu pregunta el dd que hiciste y el resultado que te dió

Comment: agregado asi se ve mejor.

Comment: Parece que la relación no está definida, tendríamos que ver la migración respectiva.

Comment: Acabo de agregar como tengo el migrations de ambas tablas

Comment: en tu migración departamentos, solo tienes declarada la columna que será usada como `FK` pero en ningún momento la vinculas con la tabla empresa, entonces te falta esto `$table->foreign('id_empresa')->references('id')->on('empresa');` agrega esto para que la relación entre empresa y departamentos esté definida

Comment: Perfecto element, eso era me faltaba el foreing en el migrations!!!! SOLUCIONADO

Comment: No sé cual es la lógica que sigue su modelado pero, no debería tener el `foreign key` en su tabla empresas? es decir en su tabla empresa un campo `departament_id` y no como lo está haciendo ahora ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando estás vinculando 2 tablas; una por su llave primaria y otra por su llave foránea, necesitas declarar este mismo comportamiento en Laravel a través de su sistema de migraciones de este modo

En tu migración departamentos solo tienes esta columna

```
$table->integer('id_empresa')->unsigned();
```

Sin embargo en ningún momento estas indicando con que otra migración o migraciones esta vinculada para actuar de `FOREING KEY` entonces justo debajo de la columna antes mencionada te hace falta lo siguiente

```
$table->foreign('id_empresa')->references('id')->on('empresa');
```

De lo anterior extraemos que:

- Usamos el método `foreign()` para indicar que la llave que pasemos como argumento será de tipo foráneo
- Usamos el método `references()` para indicar esta llave foránea con que columna de la otra tabla estará vinculada, en este caso la `PK` id de la tabla empresa
- Finalmente usamos `on()` para indicar el nombre de la tabla con la cual la vamos a vincular